# Solve $x\ln|x| > (x+1)\ln|x+1|$ analytically

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

From the plot, it is easy to see that $$x\ln|x| > (x+1)\ln|x+1|$$ holds for $-1<x<0$, but I'm confused about solving it analytically. How should I go about this?

Comment: please check the statement of the problem
it doesn't seem to be correct

Comment: Over $(0,1)$ the LHS is negative while the RHS is positive, hence the inequality cannot hold. In the converse direction, it is trivial.

Comment: @g.kov Yes. I corrected the typo.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I corrected my typo.

Answer (score 0):

For $-1<x<0$ LHS is positive, and RHS is negative due to $\log|x+1|$

Comment: That is obvious. My question was: how do I solve the inequality without knowing the result first?